# Antlr4 using fragments to exclude characters

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a working `TOKEN` that excludes certain characters. It must not start with `+` or `-`, but these characters are allowed after the start.

```
TOKEN : ~('+' | '-' | '\u0000' .. '\u001f' | ' ' | '<' | '>' | ':' | '"' | '/' | '\\' | '|' | '?' | '*' | '#' | '@') ~('\u0000' .. '\u001f' | ' ' | '<' | '>' | ':' | '"' | '/' | '\\' | '|' | '?' | '*' | '#' | '@')+ ;
```

I have been trying to simplify it using fragments...

```
fragment EXCLUDED : ('\u0000' .. '\u001f' | ' ' | '<' | '>' | ':' | '"' | '/' | '\\' | '|' | '?' | '*' | '#' | '@');
fragment RESERVED : ('+' | '-') ;
TOKEN : ~(RESERVED | EXCLUDED) ~(EXCLUDED)+ ;
```

However I get the error: `rule reference RESERVED is not currently supported in a set`?

Comment: Antlr is picky about what one can apply the `~`-operator to. It has to be a set or something that can be quickly represented as a set: a "char set" (see [doc](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-rule-elements)), a char range, or an alt expression--all of which must be for single character string literals. The developers likely felt that it would have been a lot more work to implement the use of a rule name with `~`, with not that much gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the shorter character set notation from ANTLR 4, you perhaps don't need to use the negated fragments. The rule:

```
TOKEN
 : ~('+' | '-' | '\u0000' .. '\u001f' | ' ' | '<' | '>' | ':' | '"' | '/' | '\\' | '|' | '?' | '*' | '#' | '@') ~('\u0000' .. '\u001f' | ' ' | '<' | '>' | ':' | '"' | '/' | '\\' | '|' | '?' | '*' | '#' | '@')+
 ;
```

is the same as this:

```
TOKEN
 : ~[+\-\u0000-\u001f <>:"/\\|?*#@] ~[\u0000-\u001f <>:"/\\|?*#@]+
 ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the shorter character set.  I had considered inverting the set (only the allowed characters), but the profiler showed this to be significantly slower.